# Installing SBCL 2.2.7 via asdf-vm on Mac OS X M1 leads to 'zstd.h' bug - save.c:45:11: fatal error: 'zstd.h' file not found

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl, asdf-vm

I am currently trying to install SBCL via [ASDF-VM](https://asdf-vm.com/) on an M1 Mac, and I am running into the following bug trying to build 2.2.7:

```
beginning GENESIS, creating headers in "src/runtime/genesis"

real    0m23.834s
user    0m21.823s
sys 0m1.858s
//entering make-target-1.sh
//building runtime system and symbol table file
rm -f *.[do] sbcl ldb unit-tests sbcl.h core *.tmp libsbcl.a shrinkwrap-sbcl* sbcl.mk
echo '#include "genesis/config.h"' >sbcl.h
echo '#include "genesis/constants.h"' >>sbcl.h
save.c:45:11: fatal error: 'zstd.h' file not found
# include <zstd.h>
          ^~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
coreparse.c:48:11: fatal error: 'zstd.h' file not found
# include <zstd.h>
          ^~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
cc -g -Wall -Wundef -Wsign-compare -Wpointer-arith -O3 -g -Wall -fdollars-in-identifiers -fno-omit-frame-pointer -I.  -c -o alloc.o alloc.c
cc -g -Wall -Wundef -Wsign-compare -Wpointer-arith -O3 -g -Wall -fdollars-in-identifiers -fno-omit-frame-pointer -I.  -c -o backtrace.o backtrace.c
cc -g -Wall -Wundef -Wsign-compare -Wpointer-arith -O3 -g -Wall -fdollars-in-identifiers -fno-omit-frame-pointer -I.  -c -o breakpoint.o breakpoint.c
cc -g -Wall -Wundef -Wsign-compare -Wpointer-arith -O3 -g -Wall -fdollars-in-identifiers -fno-omit-frame-pointer -I.  -c -o coalesce.o coalesce.c
cc -g -Wall -Wundef -Wsign-compare -Wpointer-arith -O3 -g -Wall -fdollars-in-identifiers -fno-omit-frame-pointer -I.  -c -o coreparse.o coreparse.c
coreparse.c:48:11: fatal error: 'zstd.h' file not found
# include <zstd.h>
          ^~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [coreparse.o] Error 1
Installed SBCL
/Users/exysle/.asdf/plugins/sbcl/bin/install: line 190: /Users/exysle/.asdf/installs/sbcl/2.2.7/bin/sbcl: No such file or directory
```

It seems like the bug is apparent in 2.2.7 and 2.2.6, but it seems like 2.2.5 installs perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

This is because SBCL 2.2.6 and later uses [zstd](https://github.com/facebook/zstd) for core compression, and presumably that does not ship with macOS (certainly I can not find it on my machine).

I do not understand asdf-vm, but it looks like the plugin for SBCL is [here](https://github.com/smashedtoatoms/asdf-sbcl), and it is significant that it *explicitly lists zstd in its prerequisites*.

You will only get this problem if you build with the `--fancy` option: unless you use that the build will not include the core compression stuff.  If I build with `./make/sh --fancy` then it fails in just this way.

A way to diagnose this is to run `./make-config.sh` and then look at what's in `local-target-features.lisp-expr`.  It should not contain any mention of `:sb-core-compression`: if it does, you'll need `zstd`.